# how to make a patch method correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web

I want to dynamically update the object when I receive a request for my endpoint (I want the method to be as compact and efficient as possible).

I would not like to do this using if-else. How to do it?

Thank you in advance for the answer)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Could you share your code or be more specific?